# Merging Access Reports

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf

I have a report in Access which currently provides all details of a particular record(say a student). So every time the user wants the consolidated data of a particular student then the application just generates a report of that student in print preview format. Its a very large report containing almost all student related data.

Now I need to have one pdf that combines reports of all the students and displays them in one single pdf i.e all the pdf's that are generated by the above method now just need to me merged into one big pdf.

Do I need to create a completely new report or Can the same be done using some other method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402653/merge-multiple-access-reports-to-one-pdf-file-using-vba

Comment: Use the one report and apply filter criteria. Criteria can be a single student ID or can be other parameters, such as ClassYear, etc. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html